# Using specific version of apt repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am wondering how can I set my apt to use specific version of a given repository? I believe that packages in repos are changing in time. So if today I set my repos to let's say Focal some version could be different in a year. What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I run "apt upgrade" it will update all packages on the systems we are using to exactly the same versions as we define today. Like I need a very strict consistency of current versions.

Can you please help me figure out what is the best known method for it?

EDIT adding some insight:
I am working in performance validation and I just want to minimize the possibility of environment affecting our results on multiple systems. I am wondering if there is a good way to do it without working with OS images.

Comment: Hello. They could be different next week. Depends on updates. You can not have an up to date system and freeze all apps to a certain time or version. Apt upgrade does what it supposed to do updates to the most current version. You can not do what you are trying to do and have a working system long term.

Comment: Why do you need "very strict consistency of current versions"? And why do yo believe "packages in repos are changing in time"? Ubuntu LTS versions are made for the exact reasons you describe. They generally stay on version, except for security updates. Some apps might get updated with major new features, as long as it doesn't break backward compatibility. If you need a package setup with 100% backward compatibility, Ubuntu LTS (Focal) will give you that.

Comment: David Okay, what are other possible solutions? Anything other than cloning the OS image?

Artur I am working in validation and want consistent environment across multiple systems. I was hoping that there are some internal Linux methods to guarantee it as working with images can be troublesome.

Comment: Are you saying you ***don't*** want security updates? If that's what you're saying, nobody can help you I'm afraid. You still haven't given the *why*..

Comment: If you want to use other packages, edit the `etc/apt/sources.list` file. Either use `nano` or `gedit` or something else. You may then have to update your version of Ubuntu to the version you have specified in your sources.

Comment: @Jeff he is saying NEVER update.

Comment: @David Well, I suppose an OS update isn't necessary to be able to use other packages from the sources. Just recommended. I guess I should have said that.

Comment: Yes Jeff but in a year some packages could be in a slightly different versions.

Comment: The only "slightly different version" would be patches (not version bumps) for CVEs and critical/high priority bugfixes. Only a very few applications --like web browsers-- receive upstream version bumps after a release. I suspect this question is unanswerable --too many unspoken assumptions, some of which may be incorrect-- without a specific example to work with.

Comment: If Ubuntu LTS releases are good enough for mission critical servers for large organizations with millions of customers, then it's probably good enough for what you're doing.  If you don't think so, can you give an example of the problem you are trying to solve? The theory "updates are always bad" is false.

Comment: Nmath In performance testing even security patch could potentially affect results.
user535733 The question is if tools crucial to our team receive only patches and not version bumps.

Thank you all for your inputs. I believe that working with OS images is my best choice.